# Help applying linear algebra and systems of equations to visual network flow problem

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, network-flow

[image]

The image above shows the "flows" of some arbitrary entities along certain paths $(i = 1,2...6)$. The value of the flow over a path is equal to $x_i$. Each dot is a "node". I need to find a system of equations such that the net flow at each node is zero. Then, I need to find the solutions to this system such that the flow *along* each path is either $1$, $0$, or $-1$.

I've found that the following system has all net flows at each node equal to zero:

$x_1 + x_6 -x_2 = 0$    ..... (describes the flow at the node between paths 1 and 2)

$x_2 - x_3=0$  ...... (the flow at node between paths $2$ and $3$, etc.)

$x_3-x_4=0$

$x_4-x_5-x_6=0$

$x_5-x_1=0$

I am pretty sure I could also represent this situation via the following system:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = x_6$

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_6 = x_5$

$x_1 + x_5 = x_6$

However, I'm not sure how to represent a "solution" here, or **how to determine the solutions such that the flow ($x_i$) along each path $(i=1,2...6)$ is either $1$, $0$, or $-1$.**

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Please don't give me the entire answer, though, as I would like to arrive at the answer myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here.

Comment: Those exponents should all be subscripts, right? You get a system of linear equations, not an inconsistent set of one-variable polynomials.

Comment: Gerry, yes!! Sorry for the confusion, I have edited it.

Comment: Hi Morgan, thanks for your comment. Am I better off using the first system I presented, or the second (if I convert the second into a homogeneous system)?